# How can I pull Twitter usernames from a list of names

Tags: excel, api, twitter

I have a lengthy list of names that I need to find the Twitter handles for. Is there anyway I can find the usernames of their accounts by inputting the list and filtering with keywords? The output would preferably be in Excel.

Comment: I now nothing about coding, only how to research and I haven't found anything that does this. I have found similar things such as pulling tweets and user info into Excel but that's given the username is already known.

Comment: What does the list of names look like?  How do you know what part of it is a Twitter handle?

Comment: The list is of all the UK MPs after the general election, (there isn't an update to date twitter list of this anywhere) so they are highly likely to have their Handle as their name. The keyword would come from their bio, for instance "MP".

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to write the code, but here are some ideas that might help. I'm assuming you are aware that a matching name can often be a totally different person, so there isn't any way you'll get perfect results. For example, if you had a name of a sitcom TV character named Joe Mayo, you might have a hard time finding him because my Twitter handle is @JoeMayo and the other guy would have to use something else.

1. Try a [user lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup) with the exact screen name. The benefit of this is if you were lucky and the names matched exactly. Another advantage is that you can set the screen_name parameter to a comma-separated list and get a lot of responses to use your rate limit more effectively.
2. Try [user search](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/search). This will bring back a list of potential user accounts, one of which might be the user. If you have some other data to correlate with, you might be able to intelligently figure out who that user is.
3. The [normal twitter search](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) is like shooting in the dark, but you might be able to use query parameters, like 'from' and 'to' that you might return something for. This wouldn't help at all if the person was never mentioned in a tweet within the last two weeks. I hesitate to even mention this, but at least you'll know what some of your limitations are.

If you have more than just the screen name, you might be able to get better results. Look at the [User object](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users) for more information on what fields are available.

Comment: Thank you for this. This gives me a strong point from which I can move forward.